# How can i compare two lists by elements using Stream Java 8?

Tags: java, list, java-stream, compare

*This is a simple task from some website.*

If a[i] > b[i], then Alice is awarded 1 point. If a[i] < b[i], then Bob is awarded 1 point.
If a[i] = b[i], then neither person receives a point.
Return: Alice's score is in the first position, and Bob's score is in the second.

*Can I write this code using stream?*

```
public static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    int alice = 0;
    int bob = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i) > b.get(i)) 
            alice++;
        else if (a.get(i) < b.get(i)) 
            bob++;
    }
    return Arrays.asList(alice, bob);
}
```

**...**

*After a little thought, I wrote this code:*

```
public static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    Integer[] result = {0, 0};
    IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.size(), b.size()))
            .map(i -> a.get(i).compareTo(b.get(i)))
            .forEach(i -> {
                if (i > 0) result[0]++;
                else if (i < 0) result[1]++;
            });
    return Arrays.asList(result);
}
```

But this code is not much more concise.
Are there ways to make the code more beautiful?

Answer (score 6):

You can make the code shorter with `filter` and `count`, but using loops is cleaner here. `Stream`s are not always the solution.

```java
return Arrays.asList(
    IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.size(), b.size())).filter(i -> a.get(i) > b.get(i)).count(),
    IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.size(), b.size())).filter(i -> a.get(i) < b.get(i)).count()
);
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8 - `partitioningBy()` & `counting()`

One of the way to solve this problem with streams performing **only one iteration** over the given set of data is to make use of the built Collectors `partitioningBy()` and `counting()`:

```
public static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    
    return IntStream.range(0, a.size())
        .map(i -> a.get(i) - b.get(i))
        .filter(i -> i != 0)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i > 0, Collectors.counting()),
            map -> Arrays.asList(map.get(true).intValue(), map.get(false).intValue())
        ));
}
```

## Java 8 - custom `Collector`

Another option would be to define a custom Collector using static factory method `Collector.of()`. As well as previous approach, it would allow to process the data using a single stream:

```
public static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    
    return IntStream.range(0, a.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            () -> new int[]{0, 0},
            (int[] score, Integer i) -> {
                if (a.get(i) > b.get(i)) score[0]++;
                if (b.get(i) > a.get(i)) score[1]++;
            },
            (int[] left, int[] right) -> {
                Arrays.setAll(left, i -> left[i] + right[i]);
                return left;
            },
            arr -> Arrays.asList(arr[0], arr[1])
        ));
}
```

## Java 12 - Collector `teeing()`

Another option that would allow to produce the result using a single stream is Java 12 Collector `teeing()`, which expects two downstream Collectors and a Function which performs a final transformation by merging the results they produced.

```
public static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    
    return IntStream.range(0, a.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.teeing(
            Collectors.filtering(i -> a.get(i) > b.get(i), Collectors.counting()),
            Collectors.filtering(i -> b.get(i) > a.get(i), Collectors.counting()),
            (alice, bob) -> List.of(alice.intValue(), bob.intValue())
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could well be overkill for your case but you could handle this as a stream reduction:

```
class Counter {
    private int bob = 0;
    private int alice = 0;

    public void accept(int index) {
        if (a[index] > b[index])
            alice++;
        else if (a[index] < b[index])
            bob++;
    }
}

Counter counter = IntStream.range(0, a.size()).boxed().reduce(new Counter(), Counter::accept);
```

Another alternative is to take advantage of `Integer.compare`:

```
List<Integer> comparisons = IntStream.range(0, a.size()).map(i -> Integer.compare(a[i], b[i]).toList();
long bob = comparisons.stream().filter(n -> n < 0).count();
int alice = comparisons.stream().filter(n -> n > 0).count();
```